# common mark migration breaks bullets formatting?

Tags: bug, markdown, formatting

After migration to common mark formatting of the bullets is corrupted. Old formatting used 1 space for inner text but common mark uses 3 spaces. So after migration the bullets where not repaired at all. example:

Mark down (on purpose with the same number):

1. **bullet**

bla bla bla

bla bla bla

1. **bullet**

bla bla bla

1. **bullet**

bla bla bla

Common mark (on purpose with the same number):

1. **bullet**

   bla bla bla

   bla bla bla
2. **bullet**

   bla bla bla
3. **bullet**

   bla bla bla

So all not-new answers using bullets are corrupted now. Can be this repaired automatically with some script?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Automated CommonMark migration ruins long list items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349034/289905)? I think posts with such lists could not be migrated and you have to be careful when editing such posts.

Comment: @user4642212 If I read it right that post is about `-` lists not `1. 2. 3.` bullets

Comment: The formatting changed in the same way for both list types. In CommonMark you need to match the indentation of paragraphs with the list numbers or bullets. Posts where this makes a difference were not migrated, regardless of list type.

Comment: @user4642212 Yep I deduced that myself before posting this but my point is I got 1600+ posts and will not correct them manually each time something changed on the site... And considering whole site there must be a lot more posts corrupted by this. So some automatic repair should be done by the site to remedy this.